# ¿Cómo establecer/asignar el value de un input a través de una consulta con AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Muy buenas.

Tengo un formulario con varios input que debo llenar automáticamente según la búsqueda realizada por el usuario. Por ahora, lo que aplico es tener un input activador de entrada para el texto a buscar. Automáticamente se hace la búsqueda en la BBDD, a través de AJAX y al encontrar un resultado dibuja los input con values definidos según los datos traídos, dentro de un div específico.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var datos;
                                                                                                
// Se comprueba si se pulsa una tecla dentro del input
$("#entrada").keyup(function(e) {

   //Se obtiene el value o texto introducido en el input
   datos = $("#entrada").val();
                                                           
   //Se hace la búsqueda                                                              
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "getDatos.php",
     data: "buscar ="+ datos,
     dataType: "html",

     error: function(){
        alert("Error en la petición de AJAX");
     },
     success: function(data){                                                    
        $("#respuesta").empty();
        $("#respuesta").append(data);
     }
  });                                                        
   });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form action="resultado.php" name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="entrada" id="entrada">

  <div id="respuesta"></div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa es que de primer plano, estos input no están visibles dentro del formulario, sólo aparecen cuando se hace una búsqueda que trae algún resultado. Por lo que el formulario no tiene un tamaño definido, aparte que este método me ha traído otros problemillas.

¿Hay alguna forma de fijar los value a los input ya establecidos dentro del HTML y no a través del método antes descrito? muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

**Primero**, dibujas los input en tu formulario inicial

```
<form action="resultado.php" name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="entrada" id="entrada">
  <input type="text" name="input_generado1" id="input_generado1" value="">
  <input type="text" name="input_generado2" id="input_generado2" value="">
</form>
```

**Segundo**, haz que tu backend devuelva json, no html.

```
if(!empty($datos)) {
  echo json_encode($datos);
  // debiera devolver algo como  {"campo1":"valor1", "campo2":"valor2"}
} else {
  // devuelves explícitamente un json vacío
  echo json_encode(['campo1'=>'', 'campo2'=>'']);
}
```

**Tercero**, haces que tu ajax pida `json`, no `html`, y usas la respuesta para actualizar el valor de los campos que ya están dibujados.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "getDatos.php",
     data: "buscar ="+ datos,
     dataType: "json",

     error: function(){
        alert("Error en la petición de AJAX");
     },
     success: function(data){                                                    
        $("#input_generado1").val(data.campo1);
        $("#input_generado2").val(data.campo2);
     }
  });
```

## Edit, dos años después

Mi respuesta en realidad sólo ofrece la solución al caso particular "input1", "input2". Pero mirando tu código, en realidad estás tratando de hacer un autocompletador, y ese autocompletador puede ofrecerte muchos, uno o ningún resultado. En tu caso, cada resultado tiene la forma de una tupla. Según los resultados que obtengas tienes que poblar el formulario con una pareja, muchas parejas o ninguna.

Debido a lo anterior, tenemos dos problemas específicamente respecto del DOM. Por un lado, no puedes asignar el atributo `name` en duro a tus resultados porque al enviar el formulario los datos se pisan (y el último se impone). Segundo, tampoco puedes darle `id` en duro porque el DOM debiera tener ids únicos. Si repites ids, el browser asume que te refieres al primero que tenga ese id.

Además, tenemos otro problema porque cuando la persona escribe tú gatillas una búsqueda, y se van a ir acumulando peticiones hasta colapsar la base de datos o el backend.

Como acá no tenemos backend, podemos hacer un mock mediante una función que devuelve una promesa (igual que jQuery.ajax) y que en este caso demora 1.5 segundos en responder. La respuesta consiste en uno o más resultados del arreglo de tuplas nombre-apellido.

En el siguiente ejemplo tenemos resuelto el problema del atributo `name` 
 dinámico. Cada resultado tiene su índice y del índice sacamos un sufijo para el atributo `name`. Por cada resultado se añade un div nuevo que se va apilando.

```js
var posibles_resultados = [{
      nombre: 'juan',
      apellido: 'perez'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'pedro',
      apellido: 'gonzales'
    },
     {
      nombre: 'capitana',
      apellido: 'marvel'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'diego',
      apellido: 'vega'
    },
     {
      nombre: 'black',
      apellido: 'widow'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'ivan',
      apellido: 'zamorano'
    }
  ],
  contenedor_resultados = jQuery('#resultados'),
  boton_busqueda = jQuery('#dame_resultados'),
  input_busqueda = jQuery('#termino');

function busquedaAjax(termino) {
  // puedes obtener de cero a cuatro resultados
  var cantidad_resultados = Math.round(Math.random() * 6)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(_.shuffle(posibles_resultados).slice(0, cantidad_resultados));
    }, 1500);
  });

}
boton_busqueda.on('click', function() {
  var termino = input_busqueda.val(),
    resultadosPromesa = busquedaAjax(termino);
  contenedor_resultados.empty().append('<div id="buscando">Buscando...</div>');
  resultadosPromesa.then((resultados) => {
    if(resultados.length===0) {
    jQuery('#buscando').text('No hubo resultados');
    }
    contenedor_resultados.empty();
    resultados.forEach((resultado,indice) => {
      jQuery('<div class="tupla">')
        .append(`<label>Nombre ${indice}:</label><input type="text" value="${resultado.nombre}"  name="nombre_${indice}">`)
        .append(`<label>Apellido ${indice}:</label><input type="text" value="${resultado.apellido}" name="apellido_${indice}">`)
        .addClass('shown')
        .appendTo(contenedor_resultados);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#resultados .tupla {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  margin:0.1em;
}

#resultados .tupla.shown {
  opacity: 1;
}
#buscando {
padding:10px;
font-size:0.9em;
}
#resultados .tupla label {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="termino" placeholder="ingrese término a buscar" />
<button id="dame_resultados">Dame resultados</button>
<div id="resultados"></div>
```

Por simplicidad usé un botón en vez de una caja de texto. Mira lo que pasa si apretas el botón cinco veces sin esperar al resultado: empieza a escupir resultados que se van pisando. Eso no sólo le pega fuerte al backend y BBDD sino que es una mala experiencia de usuario.

Lo que se me ocurre, en cambio es que hagas un [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce). Hay mil maneras de hacer un debounce pero yo soy fan de lodash. Básicamente, la función no se ejecuta realmente hasta que has dejado de invocarla en un cierto intervalo. O sea, si presionas el botón 5 veces rápidamente y luego esperas, sólo la quinta ocasión se gatillará.

```js
var posibles_resultados = [{
      nombre: 'juan',
      apellido: 'perez'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'pedro',
      apellido: 'gonzales'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'capitana',
      apellido: 'marvel'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'diego',
      apellido: 'vega'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'black',
      apellido: 'widow'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'ivan',
      apellido: 'zamorano'
    }
  ],
  contenedor_resultados = jQuery('#resultados'),
  boton_busqueda = jQuery('#dame_resultados'),
  input_busqueda = jQuery('#termino');

function busquedaAjax(termino) {
  // puedes obtener de cero a cuatro resultados
  var cantidad_resultados = Math.round(Math.random() * 6)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(_.shuffle(posibles_resultados).slice(0, cantidad_resultados));
    }, 1500);
  });

}

var busquedaDebounced = _.debounce(function() {
  var termino = input_busqueda.val(),
    resultadosPromesa = busquedaAjax(termino);
  contenedor_resultados
    .empty()
    .append('<div id="buscando">Ok ahora sí buscando...</div>');
  resultadosPromesa.then((resultados) => {
    if (resultados.length === 0) {
      jQuery('#buscando').text('No hubo resultados :(');
      return;
    }
    contenedor_resultados.empty();
    resultados.forEach((resultado, indice) => {
      jQuery('<div class="tupla">')
        .append(`<label>Nombre ${indice}:</label><input type="text" value="${resultado.nombre}"  name="nombre_${indice}">`)
        .append(`<label>Apellido ${indice}:</label><input type="text" value="${resultado.apellido}" name="apellido_${indice}">`)
        .addClass('shown')
        .appendTo(contenedor_resultados);
    });
  });
}, 2000);

boton_busqueda.on('click', function() {
  contenedor_resultados
    .empty()
    .append('<div id="buscando">Muchos clicks...</div>');
  busquedaDebounced();
});
```

```css
#resultados .tupla {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

#resultados .tupla.shown {
  opacity: 1;
}

#buscando {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

#resultados .tupla label {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="termino" placeholder="ingrese término a buscar" />
<button id="dame_resultados">Dame resultados</button>
<div id="resultados"></div>
```

Y eso querido público es el ejercicio de hoy. La implementación en PHP pasa en buenas cuentas por sustituir la mecánica de la función `busquedaAjax` por el caso real. Pero eso queda de tarea.